# ssh reverse tunnel works, autossh does not

Tags: ssh, openvpn, autossh

I have to access an openvpn-vpn server behind a firewall, so to do this I use an ssh-reverse tunnel. While using the "normal" `ssh` command works, connecting via `autossh` does not. For all the other connections `autossh` works fine.

- SSH-Command:

  ```
  ssh -R 0.0.0.0:8888:localhost:1194 user@server -N
  ```
- Autossh-Command:

  ```
  /usr/bin/autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -N -R 0.0.0.0:8888:localhost:1149 user@server
  ```
- Error message while trying to connect with `autossh`:

  ```
  debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:1149) in progress, fd=7
  debug3: channel 2: waiting for connection
  debug1: channel 2: connection failed: Connection refused
  connect_to localhost port 1149: failed.
  debug3: send packet: type 92
  debug2: channel 2: zombie
  debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
  debug1: channel 2: free: 193.175.84.201, nchannels 3
  debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  ```

I don't know what the difference might be here, anyone knows what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, for anyone who has the same problem:

Instead of:

```
/usr/bin/autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -N -R 0.0.0.0:8888:localhost:1149 user@server
```

The command needs to be like this:

```
/usr/bin/autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 0.0.0.0:8888:localhost:1194 user@server -N
```

So the `-N` option needs to be *at the end*.